# C# WPF change ImageSource Image on Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to update an ImageSource with an image on runtime from a different thread then the main_UI one, but for some reason i keep getting: 
`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`
I have tried a few things:

- `im_Cover.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { if (im_Cover.Source != image) im_Cover.Source = image; });`
- `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { im_Cover.Source = image; }));`
- Freezing the image (which was not possible). I tried to add a messagebox on the error and once the error showed up and I pressed OK, for some reason, the image did load.
- Tried using a custom downloadcompleted eventhandler which didn't even fire.

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < correctArtist.images.Count; i++)
{
if (correctArtist.images[i].width > correctArtist.images[biggest].width)
   biggest = i;
}
Image biggestImage = correctArtist.images[biggest];
var imgUrl = biggestImage.url;

image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgUrl));


bool uiAccessCover = im_Cover.Dispatcher.CheckAccess();
if (uiAccessCover)
{
    im_Cover.Source = image;
}
else
{
    //im_Cover.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { if (im_Cover.Source != image) im_Cover.Source = image; });
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { im_Cover.Source = image; }));
}
```

And for some reason this: `lb_Song.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { if ((string)lb_Song.Content != song) lb_Song.Content = song; });` does work.

Any idea why it doesn't work, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before passing a BitmapImage from a background thread to the UI thread by e.g.

```
im_Cover.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => im_Cover.Source = image));
```

it *must* be frozen. Otherwise it must also be created on the UI thread, like

```
im_Cover.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    im_Cover.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgUrl))));
```

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. Thanks!!